# Javascript function not updating HTML block - should it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a CSHTML page that generates a web page which includes a button that calls a JavaScript function (on the same page) which makes an AJAX call and updates a  block with the results.  It looks like this:

```
function getItems()
{
    $(result_div).html("<b>Processing...</b>");       
    var resultString = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetItems", "DataHandler.svc")',
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            resultString = "<b>Items:</b><br />";
            var itemNames = data;
            for (var N in itemNames) {
                resultString += (itemNames[N] + "<br />");
            }
        },
        error: function (HelpRequest, ErrorCode, TheError) {
            resultString = "Error creating items list:<br />" + TheError;
        },
        async: false
    });
    $(result_div).html(resultString);
}
```

When I press the button, the function is called, and eventually the correct data is displayed in the "result_div"  block; however, the block is not updated until the function returns, rather than immediately displaying "Processing..." as I wanted.

However, if I have this instead:

```
function getItems()
{
    var resultString = "<b>Processing...</b>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetItems", "DataHandler.svc")',
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            resultString = "<b>Items:</b><br />";
            var itemNames = data;
            for (var N in itemNames) {
                resultString += (itemNames[N] + "<br />");
            }
        },
        error: function (HelpRequest, ErrorCode, TheError) {
            resultString = "Error creating items list:<br />" + TheError;
        },
        complete: function (Request, Status) {
            $(result_div).html(resultString);     
        }
    });
    $(result_div).html(resultString);
}
```

then it does immediately display "Processing..." before that is replaced with the data.

Am I wrong in assuming that the .html call would update the  immediately?  Is it waiting for the function to finish before refreshing the page?

Comment: what value do you have in variable `result_div `?

Comment: Initially?  Just "&nbsp;"

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, any variable declared outside will be undefined inside ;) Also `result_div` must be a container tag like a div/span etc

Comment: It's not exactly a variable - in the <body> block of the html, I have:

    <div id="result_div">&nbsp;</div>

This is where the result of the function call goes (successfully).

Comment: @DonDelGrande dowvote for what exactly??????

Comment: @DonDelGrande you need to have a container tag mate ! + on success only fill that element ;)

Comment: @Tushar this is what i said and ended up with a downote :(

Comment: @Tushar - I think you misunderstand what I am trying to do.
What I want it to do is this:

1. Show "Processing..." in the area of the web page where the result will go, so the user knows that something is happening

2. Get the data through the call to the function in the service (i.e. the GetItems function in the DataHandler service)

3.  Replace the "Processing..." message with the returned data.

It is doing (2) and (3) - just not (1).
The Ajax call has async=false because I do not want the user to be able to do anything before the data is retrieved.

Comment: @Rhea I don't see the comment that was downvoted.  It's possible that I accidentally did it when trying to edit a comment I posted before finishing it (by not holding down Ctrl when pressing Enter - apparently, that's important in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling people are misunderstanding my "problem," so I will try to make it clearer.

My cshtml looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="result_div">
    &nbsp;
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id="button_getItems" onclick="getItems()">
    Get Items
    </button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getItems()
    {
        $(result_div).html("<b>Processing...</b>");       
        var resultString = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItems", "DataHandler.svc")',
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                resultString = "<b>Items:</b><br />";
                var itemNames = data;
                for (var N in itemNames) {
                    resultString += (itemNames[N] + "<br />");
                }
            },
            error: function (HelpRequest, ErrorCode, TheError) {
                resultString = "Error creating items list:<br />" + TheError;
            }
            , async: false
        });
        $(result_div).html(resultString);
    }
</script>
```

What happens when I press the "Get Items" button is, it pauses for a few seconds while the data is being extracted, and then the data appears on the screen above the button - like it is supposed to.  The problem is not that "the data is not appearing at all."  That part works fine.

What I expected it to do is, when I press the button, "Processing..." is supposed to appear in the time before the data is retrieved and displayed.

This is what happens when I use my "alternative" version of getItems() (the one with "async: false" removed, resultString initially set to "Processing:", and a "complete:" section added to the Ajax call that sets the result_div block to the returned data.
However, I don't want to make the call asynchronous as I don't want the user to be able to do anything while the data is being extracted.

Comment: It works out fine when I try it. I used `http://google.com:81` as the URL so it will timeout. It displays `Processing...` and then it displays `Error creating items list:` a few seconds later.